# Unable to validate for primefaces event blur?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

> I am not able to validate input fields using primefaces ajax on the client side by calling event blur using primefaces

```
 <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel for="uname"  value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText   id="uname"  value="#{userbean.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter your name">
                <p:ajax event="blur" rendererType="name"/>
            </p:inputText>


            <h:outputText value=""/>
            <p:message id="name" for="uname" />

            <p:outputLabel for="add"  value="Address"/>
            <p:inputText   id="add" value="#{userbean.address}"   required="true" requiredMessage="Enter your address">
                <p:ajax event="blur" rendered="address"/>
            </p:inputText>


            <h:outputText value=""/>
            <p:message id="address" for="add" />

            <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: what are you doing with rendered and renderType on the p:ajax? I am assuming you want to update a field, they should be update="name" etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're doing with 'rendererType and rendered' on your ajax events - they make no sense and ikely just breaking.

I've got it working fine in the below example (note my bean is different name) - i made the grid only 1 in colum size just for testing purposes and you're best off wrapping those full data objects you want re-rendered after ajax request. see the below code p:ajax uses 'update' to render content, where f:ajax uses render="id" etc..

```
 <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="nameSection" >
            <p:outputLabel for="uname"  value="Name"/> 

            <p:inputText id="uname"  value="#{onBlur.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter your name">
                <p:ajax event="blur" update="nameSection"/>
            </p:inputText>


            <h:outputText value=""/>
            <p:message id="name" for="uname" />
        </h:panelGroup> 

        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="addressSection" >
            <p:outputLabel for="add"  value="Address"/>
            <p:inputText id="add" value="#{onBlur.address}"   required="true" requiredMessage="Enter your address">
                <p:ajax event="blur" update="addressSection"/>
            </p:inputText>

            <h:outputText value=""/>
            <p:message id="address" for="add" />
         </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Any reason why this was downvoted? comment would be nice... If you wanted further info on the renderType/rendered on ajax - refer to document guide : http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/ajax.html

Comment: Not sure why; it's a valid answer. If the downvoter feels strongly enough about it, OD will come back to explain.

Comment: My fault: it was an unwanted downvote. And I could not untoggle it because the answer hasn't been edited anymore.